# cplex presolver without invoking the cplex mip solver

Tags: c, cplex

Is it possible to run the cplex presolver to aggregate a problem without invoking the the mip solver? If it is, could you provide an example using the c callable library?

Comment: I don't know if it can be done as a C callable library but are you just trying to generate the models?

Comment: I'm filling up a model a little at a time due to memory limitations. Most of the rows could be aggregated since they are linear combination of other rows.

Comment: Is your problem really so big that you need to worry about this incremental aggregating? What makes you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to call presolve independently. The function you're looking for is [CPXpresolve](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/presolve.html). The example given in the documentation is:

> status = CPXpresolve (env, lp, CPX_ALG_DUAL);

You may also be interested in [CPXpreslvwrite](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/preslvwrite.html). Here's the example for that (also from the documentation):

> status = CPXpreslvwrite (env, lp, "myfile.pre", &objoff);

If you write out the presolved problem, as above, you can read it back in with CPXreadcopyprob. This will allow you to work with the presolved problem directly.